# Can't open script file in Mono Develop after update unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I update my Unity from 5.2 to 5.6, this is success. But after update, i can't open file script. This is Error

> The file '/Users/vietbac/Desktop/New Unity Project 1/Assets/NewBehaviourScript.cs' could not be opened. Error while loading style :Default
>
> System.IO.IOException: Error while loading style :Default --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException:
>   /Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/libgdiplus.dylib
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup
>   (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
>   at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Drawing.ColorConverter.StaticConvertFromString
>   (ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.String s,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Drawing.ColorConverter.ConvertFrom
>   (ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom (System.Object o)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromString (System.String
>   text) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml (System.String htmlColor)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ColorScheme.GetColorFromString
>   (System.String colorString) [0x001c0] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/ColorScheme.cs:578
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ColorScheme.SetChunkStyle
>   (System.String name, System.String weight, System.String foreColor,
>   System.String backColor) [0x00038] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/ColorScheme.cs:514
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ColorScheme.ReadStyleTree
>   (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ColorScheme
>   result, System.String curName, System.String curWeight, System.String
>   curColor, System.String curBgColor) [0x000b8] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/ColorScheme.cs:599
>   at
>   Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ColorScheme+c__AnonStorey32.<>m__43
>   () [0x000e0] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/ColorScheme.cs:625
>   at
>   Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.XmlReadHelper+c__AnonStorey19.<>m__D
>   (Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ReadCallbackData data) [0x00000] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/XmlReadHelper.cs:55
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.XmlReadHelper.ReadList
>   (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, ICollection`1 endNodes,
>   Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ReaderCallbackWithData callback)
>   [0x0008b] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/XmlReadHelper.cs:91
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.XmlReadHelper.ReadList
>   (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, ICollection`1 endNodes,
>   Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ReaderCallback callback) [0x0000d] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/XmlReadHelper.cs:54
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.XmlReadHelper.ReadList
>   (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.String endNode,
>   Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ReaderCallback callback) [0x00000] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/XmlReadHelper.cs:50
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ColorScheme.LoadFrom
>   (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00018] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/ColorScheme.cs:615
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.SyntaxModeService.LoadStyle
>   (System.String name) [0x0003c] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/SyntaxModeService.cs:111
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.SyntaxModeService.LoadStyle
>   (System.String name) [0x00053] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/SyntaxModeService.cs:113
>   at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.SyntaxModeService.GetColorStyle
>   (System.String name) [0x0002c] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/SyntaxModeService.cs:83
>   at Mono.TextEditor.TextEditorOptions.GetColorStyle () [0x00000] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor/TextEditorOptions.cs:492
>   at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.StyledSourceEditorOptions.GetColorStyle ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/StyledSourceEditorOptions.cs:192
>   at Mono.TextEditor.TextArea.OptionsChanged (System.Object sender,
>   System.EventArgs args) [0x00038] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor/Gui/TextArea.cs:685
>   at Mono.TextEditor.TextArea.set_Options (ITextEditorOptions value)
>   [0x00066] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor/Gui/TextArea.cs:157
>   at Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor.set_Options (ITextEditorOptions value)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor/Gui/TextEditor.cs:414
>   at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.ExtensibleTextEditor..ctor
>   (MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView view) [0x00028] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/ExtensibleTextEditor.cs:75
>   at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorWidget..ctor
>   (MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView view) [0x00077] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SourceEditorWidget.cs:284
>   at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView..ctor () [0x000ca] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SourceEditorView.cs:189
>   at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorDisplayBinding.CreateContent
>   (FilePath fileName, System.String mimeType,
>   MonoDevelop.Projects.Project ownerProject) [0x00000] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SourceEditorDisplayBinding.cs:94
>   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.LoadFileWrapper.Invoke (System.String fileName)
>   [0x00033] in
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/monodevelop/build/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/Workbench.cs:1182

Comment: Never had this issue. Nevertheless If this problem occured only in one file you could just open in notepad create new script in unity and copy content

Comment: I think this is a MonoDevelop problem and has nothing to do with the script files. Try Visual Studio or some other editor... like notepad... if you've got an extra pair of titanium balls

Comment: Burn MonoDevelop in the hottest fire you can find. Then get Visual Studio, its so much better.